# Run all classes and save all execution data in report with ant and Junit

Tags: ant, junit

I have created a build file, and configured it according to my project (Selenium and Junit).
Now the issue is when i run build file, it only runs the first class and saves the same in HTML report.
Can any one tell me what m doing wrong and what should be edited / or replaced??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ant" default="exec" basedir=".">

    <property name="src" value="./src" />
    <property name="lib" value="./lib" />
    <property name="bin" value="./bin" />
    <property name="report" value="./report" />
    <path id="ant.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${bin}" />
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <include name="C:/Users/bhmehta/workspace/ant/lib/libs/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <delete dir="${bin}" />
        <mkdir dir="${bin}" />
    </target>

      <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source " >
         <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
            <javac debug="true" 
                srcdir="${src}" 
                destdir="${bin}"    
                includeantruntime="false"
                classpathref="ant.classpath"/>
                <!-- Copy files from ${src} into ${build} -->
            <copy todir="${bin}"> 
                <fileset dir="${src}">
                    <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
            </copy>
      </target>

    <target name="exec" depends="compile">
        <delete dir="${report}" />
        <mkdir dir="${report}" />
        <mkdir dir="${report}/xml" />
            <junit 
                printsummary="yes" 
                haltonfailure="no"
                >
                <classpath><pathelement location="${ant.classpath}" /> </classpath>     

                <test  name="testing.demo" haltonfailure="no" todir="${report}/xml" outfile="TEST-result">
                        <formatter type="xml" />
                </test>         

                <test  name="testing.demo1" haltonfailure="no" todir="${report}/xml" outfile="TEST-result">
                                        <formatter type="xml" />
                </test>

            </junit>
            <junitreport todir="${report}">
                <fileset dir="${report}/xml">
                    <include name="TEST*.xml" />
                </fileset>
                <report format="frames" todir="${report}/html" />
            </junitreport>
    </target>
</project>
```

I have also tried some of the solutions given to similar questions, using `<batchtest   </batchtest>` tags. But it shows error like

```
The <junit> type doesn't support ne sted text data (">").
```

I really don't know what is this all about.
Please some one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your batchtest. Should be: `<batchtest> </batchtest>`. Try this:

```
<junit haltonfailure="no" printsummary="yes" fork="yes">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${ant.classpath}" />
    </classpath>
    <formatter type="xml"/>
    <batchtest todir="${report}">
        <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.class" />
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Once your tests will run, configure the build the way you need.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, it executes fine but the report are blank.

Comment: Nopes Michael, i am still getting the reports as below 'Tests Failures Errors Skipped Success rate Time
0 0 0 0 NaN 0.000'

Comment: My project structure is like this .. may be it can help you...  `C:.
+---.settings
+---bin
¦   +---testingnd 
+---lib
¦   +---libs
+---report
¦   +---html
¦   +---xml
+---src
    +---testing`

Comment: I think i`ve found out. You are compiling sources to 'bin' folder, but we are running tests from 'src'. You should change to <fileset dir="bin".

Comment: i tried one thing .. i added `<batchtest todir="${report}/xml">` instead of `<batchtest todir="${report}"`.. so this showing in report ..but now in report..all class files are showing errors as 'testing.demo
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testing.demo
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
'

Comment: also i changes the src path to bin

Comment: Check that 'ant.classpath' contains all jars, that you are using in your code

Comment: Looks like I haven't looked at your 'ant.classpath'. Try to change classpath inside your junit tag to this  <classpath refid="$ant.classpath"/>

Comment: i had tried all stuff.. but still that exception.. have cross chked all libs and dir..

Comment: The problem is in 'classpath' inside the junit block. Try different variants for it. Other code seems legit.

Comment: Yes it might be the only reason.I have added juit's jar, selenium jar...anything else to be added??

Comment: The main thing is your compiled sources path.

Comment: Yes added that too. But it should be having the package name in path? In my case, `C:\Users\bhmehta\workspace\ant\bin\testing` , "testing" is the package in the project.

Comment: @Michael... Thanks Man .. that was the stupid mistake i was doing. Now its working. Great.. thanks again

Comment: You`re welcome! I step into this just every time, when I`m working with classpathes :)